# How to post data and redirect to another page using GWT?

Tags: gwt, spring-mvc

When I press a button I post some data to server and there redirect to another page. 
I used RequestBuilder but it is waiting the response, and of course get it. And nothing happens, same page stays. I see RequestBuidler shouldn't be used here... What should I use to post data and be able to redirect?

In Spring

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/ddd")
public ModelAndView processOrder(@RequestBody String orderInString, HttpSession session) throws Exception{
    ...
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("abc"));

}
```

In GWT

```
public void postData(final String data, final String url) {
    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, url);
    try {
        builder.sendRequest(data, new RequestCallback() {
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                ...
            }

            public void onResponseReceived(Request request,
                    Response response) {
                if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                    ..
                } else {
                    ..
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (RequestException e) {
        ...
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    FormPanel form = new FormPanel("_self");
    form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_GET);

    Hidden params0 = new Hidden("param1", "value1");
    Hidden params1 = new Hidden("param1", "value2");
    Hidden params2 = new Hidden("param2", "value3");

    FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
    panel.add(params0);
    panel.add(params1);
    panel.add(params2);

    form.add(panel);

    form.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "../MyServlet");
    RootPanel.get().add(form);
    form.submit();
```

Thats it. The code adds FormPanel and sends form.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for advice. Strange is that I get exception when trying to add param to form: form.add(param);
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SimplePanel can only contain one child widget
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SimplePanel.add(SimplePanel.java:57)
    at com.webshop.client.HelloGwt$5.onClick(HelloGwt.java:271)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:54)

Comment: You can't add parameters directly to FormPanel it's single widget panel. The only way to add many parameters is to add them through an other panel. In this example it is FlowPanel. Reember that it is only container for params.
Here you have extended tutorial: http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Panels~FormPanel.
Please accept my answer as a solution.

Comment: Thanks for reply! But still, browser doesn't refresh page after form.submit() is done! The same page stays! Is it same asynchronous call, i mean form.submit()? I tried my controller from browser, changing method to GET, and it worked (redirected to new url), but from java script not!

Comment: +1 It's great. You gave the answer to the very important question.

Answer (score 0):

Add more specifications, code, this is blur.
Since you are using Spring-mvc, you should be having something like this

```
 private static final String newPage = "index2";  //this is resolved with view resolver
 @RequestMapping(params = "action=button")
 protected String getALPLicense(final RenderRequest request,
            final RenderResponse response, final Model model) throws Exception {
 try{
 }catch{
 }
 return newPage;  //this is your new redirected page
 }
```