# GWT- POST object/json and go to another page

Tags: java, json, post, gwt, dictionary

I referred this link : [How to post data and redirect to another page using GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943058/how-to-post-data-and-redirect-to-another-page-using-gwt)

I can use formpanel but I am stuck somewhere ,please help .

This is my code :

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.add(...some information....); //want to send this map in POST
```

I want to send the map using POST and also I want to go to another page.

### I can use this code (answered in [How to post data and redirect to another page using GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943058/how-to-post-data-and-redirect-to-another-page-using-gwt)):

```
 FormPanel form = new FormPanel("_self");
form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_GET);

Hidden params0 = new Hidden("param1", "value1");
Hidden params1 = new Hidden("param1", "value2");
Hidden params2 = new Hidden("param2", "value3");

FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
panel.add(params0);
panel.add(params1);
panel.add(params2);

form.add(panel);

form.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "../test");
RootPanel.get().add(form);
form.submit();
```

But how do I send already created map along with POST ?

### At server side  :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/test",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public String test(@RequestBody final HashMap<String, String> map,HttpSession session)
{
    //use the map
    return another-page.jsp
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably better to send data via RPC or AJAX and redirect to another page by Location.assign() or Location.replace(). If you expect the server to provide dynamic URL to redirect you can send it as a response for the RPC or AJAX request. In current example AJAX request is used:

```
// map is your existing map object
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    data.put(key, new JSONString(map.get(key)));
}

RequestBuilder request = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, "<URL>");
request.setRequestData(data.toString());
request.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
        String url = response.getText();

        // url to redirect
        Window.Location.assign(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
        // handle error
    }
});

request.send();
```

Or you can serialize map to String and pass it as hidden field of a POST request.

Client code:

```
String buffer = Streamer.get().toString(map);

FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
panel.add(new Hidden("map", buffer));

FormPanel form = new FormPanel("_self");
form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
form.setAction(<URL>);
form.add(panel);
RootPanel.get().add(form);

form.submit();
```

Server code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = <URL>,method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public String test(@RequestBody String mapString,HttpSession session)
{
    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) Streamer.get().fromString(mapString);

    // use the map
    return another-page.jsp
}
```

Comment: The problem is I want to use this map obj in that redirected page. currently as a workaround, I have created one call using requestbuilder,that will go to server and save the map in session. and in "onResponseReceived" I have redirected to another page using Window.location method.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to solve the problem and your solution is the most common. You can serialize map to string and put into the form hidden field and on the server side deserialize it (f.e. with this lib [gwt-streamer](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-streamer/) ). If the map is not big you can do it without posting. Also You can store map in local storage if it is required on client side.

Comment: "serialize map to string and put into the form hidden field" Can you provide me some example of it ???